# How to make web page scroll to top of page when refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After about two hours of searching I still can't find a way on how to make my top page instantly appear after a refresh. So far the only way to do so is to use the jquery and javascript scroll effect which takes forever to scroll to the top. So the scrolling effect is basically useless. Is there another way to do it like how you would give a tag an id in html and it immediately redirect you to a specific location of the page when you click on a link without having the scroll effects of javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to achieve it, plain JavaScript can do it.

Using `window.scoll(0, 0)`, you scroll to the top instantly. If you want it to be after the complete load of the page, wrap it in a `$().ready()`.

```
$().ready(function() {
   window.scroll(0, 0);
});
```

You can alternatively add an anchor at the top that you can scroll to, by using the `name` attribute of a HTML element (which you can make invisible by having no value to it).

```html
<a name="top"></a>
```

```
$().ready(function() {
    document.location.href="#top";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a one-liner vanilla javascript code.

```
window.scroll(0,0);
```

You may want to execute this code outside your Jquery document ready function if you are using jquery or DOMContentLoaded function if using pure javascript, to avoid any scrolling effect.